# Calculating time between two buttons pressed does not match the reality in Emulator

Tags: java, android

Update: Turned out it works on real device but not on emulator!!

I have two buttons and I will click one and start timer and then click other button and stop the timer. When I look at the difference it is always differs drastically from the reallity: like the stopwatch shows 15 sec but the code shows 3sec. What am I missing?!

```
Long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Long differenz = ((endtime-starttime) / 1000);
```

I also tried with System.nanoTime(); but no difference.

```
public OnClickListener startButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View theView) {

            //start music
            ding.start();

            //start timer
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            startTime1= System.nanoTime();
            Log.d(TAG, "The start time isCurrent: " + startTime);
            Log.d(TAG, "The start time isNano: " + startTime1);

        }

    };

public OnClickListener stopButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View theView) {

            //stop timer
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            endTime1= System.nanoTime();
            Log.d(TAG, "The stop time isCurrent: " + endTime);
            Log.d(TAG, "The stop time isNano: " + endTime1);
            //stop music
            ding.stop();

            //show the time on text view
            difference = (endTime-startTime) ;

            difference1 = (endTime1-startTime1) ;
            String difference_str = Long.toString(difference1);
            textView.setText(difference_str);
            Log.d(TAG, "The difference isCurrent: " + difference);
            Log.d(TAG, "The difference isNano: " + difference1);


            try {
                ding.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    };
```

Comment: That code is mostly fine, the issue has to be somewhere else. Maybe it helps if you post more of your code.

Comment: I uploaded the two ocClickListeners of two buttons

Comment: Are you testing with an emulator or device

Comment: Emulator. That can be a problem???

Comment: This is Soo weird. It works in real device and not Emulator. What is emulator for really?!

Comment: Thst's the difference between an emulator and a simulator.

Comment: emulator is not a simulator (like in iOS)

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
Time start = new Time();
start.setToNow();

// yada yada yada

Time end = new Time();
end.setToNow();

long diff = end.toMillis(true) - start.toMillis(true);
```

Comment: This is same as others too.